# g++ compile error while compiling successfully in CLion

Tags: c++, g++, clion, clang++

My device is Apple Macbook Pro 14-inch 2021 with M1 pro silicon.

I programed the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> grid;
    grid.push_back({0, 13, 2, 7, 20});
    grid.push_back({3, 8, 19, 12, 15});
    grid.push_back({18, 1, 14, 21, 6});
    grid.push_back({9, 4, 23, 16, 11});
    grid.push_back({24, 17, 10, 5, 22});
}
```

then I compile the cpp file in my terminal with:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main
```

however compilnation error with these info:

```
error: a space is required between consecutive right angle brackets (use '> >')
    vector<vector<int>> grid;

error: expected expression
    grid.push_back({0, 13, 2, 7, 20});

error: expected expression
    grid.push_back({3, 8, 19, 12, 15});

expected expression
    grid.push_back({18, 1, 14, 21, 6});

expected expression
    grid.push_back({9, 4, 23, 16, 11});

expected expression
    grid.push_back({24, 17, 10, 5, 22});
```

while I run it on CLion, there is nothing wrong.

I know there must be something wrong in g++ configuration, anybody knows how to solve this problem?

I tried it in CLion, and nothing wrong.

Comment: Maybe some old compiler. Which version are you using?

Comment: Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

Comment: Not clang, give g++ version since you are facing issue with that.

Comment: Apple Clang defaults to c++98, you need to specify c++11 to not need to put spaces between consecutive `>`s

Comment: @kiner_shah on macos `g++` is clang

Comment: I successfully compiled with `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main`. But while I use VSCode, I don't know how to configure c++ environment, if I use coderunner, the default command line is `g++ xxx.cpp -o xxx`. So must I add `-std=c++11`' every time? And how to solve the problem(run code) in VScode?

Comment: Don't use code runner, use a proper build system like cmake, if you use the cmake plugin for vscode it'll even automatically configure intellisense for you

Comment: Code runner [documentation](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: @BruceYang - If you are writing new code, there is no reason to settle for C++11. You would be a lot better off with C++17 or C++20. You don't want to learn old stuff!